# how to onClick function with a variable inside a dynamic created content

Tags: javascript, html

again with a problem

This is my dynamic created content:

```
var content =
      $('<div data-role="collapsible" id="set"' + naslov + '">'+
            '<h3>Sectionit ' + naslov + '</h3>'+
            '<p>' + opis + '</p>'+
            '<a data-ajax="false" href="#" onclick="poslinapri('+niz+')" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"><div class="prostor1tr">More</div></a>'+
         '</div>');
```

the problem is that I want in the onClick function to pass a sting not a variable ....
lets say that var `niz= "hello"` .... but I want it to apper as `onclick="poslinapri('hello')`...

I tried a few things with  quotes and double quotes ... but no success ...  so can anybody help me here ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your single quotes with backslashes, as is often the case with several levels of embedded single/double quotes.

```
var content =
      $('<div data-role="collapsible" id="set"' + naslov + '">'+
            '<h3>Sectionit ' + naslov + '</h3>'+
            '<p>' + opis + '</p>'+
            '<a data-ajax="false" href="#" onclick="poslinapri(\''+niz+'\')" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"><div class="prostor1tr">More</div></a>'+
         '</div>');
```

Here is a simple example to illustrate the point

```
var content = 'Bob\'s Burgers';
alert(content);
```

will yield an alert box with `Bob's Burgers`

Comment: You're most welcome. Make sure that any text in the `niz` variable is replacing `'` with `\'` as well. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (after you created content):

```
content.find('.ui-btn').click(function() {
  poslinapri(niz)
});
```

Thus you dont have to write `onclick="poslinapri('+niz+')"`